# Confusion with serial controlled mux devices

Tags: signal, serial, multiplexer

I have 8 channels each with 3 possible unique inputs, see diagram below. I would like to be able to select which input each output connects to. The inputs are signals from ranging from a simple step to sine/square/triangle waves up to 4Mhz, 5V peak to peak.

Ideally I would like to send my selection choice via I2C or SPI & this is where my confusion starts. When ever I look for I2C mux or I2C switches I'm just running into devices that fan out the I2C signal eg the PCA9546A or the TCA9548A. This is NOT what I want. I specifically want to be able to choose between 3 analog inputs for a given channel.

What keywords should I be using? That is assuming such devices exist

[image]

Comment: "Analog Mux" and/or "Analog Switch", then specify the control bus (parallel, serial I2C, serial SPI ...).

Answer (score 0):

Look for [analog switches](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/interface-analog-switches-multiplexers-demultiplexers/747), Another option is using an SPI GPIO expander with a regular analog switches.

I also use the ADG1611 which is an analog mux, but use the MCP23S09 as a SPI I/O expander